# SharePoint 2013: item deletion sending mail to user - Do not want

Tags: sharepoint

Mysterious situation, hoping someone has an idea what else to check.
User received mail notification that a task item was deleted.
The usual bog standard "item was deleted..." notification mail.
This should not happen.

- No workflows on this list or site
- The user has no alerts set for the list or site
- The "send mail when assigned" option is set to "No"

Normally I'd ignore it because whatevs, but this is the CDO of the agency and she needs to know other users will not receive these messages, and I need to make sure this list is kosher.

I'm completely at a loss as to how on earth she is receiving these mails. Any ideas on what else I can check?

[image]

Comment: any event receiver on the list?

Comment: nope, no event receiver going on